# auto_increment in MySQL - can I omit it?

Tags: mysql

I've noticed that PHPmyAdmin creates the following SQL for table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE something (
    ...
) auto_increment=1;
```

When I write a database creation script I don't use the auto_increment bit. From reading related questions here I understand that it determines the starting value for auto_increment values. But it is good practice to reset it to 1, or should I just leave it out of the SQL so that the default is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave it out.

The default should be 1, but you can specify that part of the script to use a different seed.

Comment: OK, in that case I'll leave it out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It has no meaning, as long as you have unique id's. Don't worry about the value.